# Tomcat application cannot be started when deployed from Netbeans

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans

when deploying a tomcat application from Netbeans, this is logged in Tomcat server Window:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE

Action:

If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).

28-Dec-2018 12:10:30.882 GRAVE [http-nio-8080-exec-7] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Error durante el despliegue del descriptor de configuraciÃ³n [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\conf\Catalina\localhost\myapp.xml]
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child
```

myapp.xml file has this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context docBase="C:\thepath\app" path="/myapp"/>
```

And finally, C:\thepath\app folder contains a WEB-INF and META-INF folders with all content in there.

How can I solve it?

Regards
Jaime

EDIT:

This is the main class:

```
package com.myapp;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan(basePackages = "myapp.model")
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = {CustomApplication.class})
public class CustomApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(CustomApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CustomApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

and this is application.parameters.yml file:

```
---
# APP
server:
  address: 0.0.0.0
  port: 8080
  context-path: /myapp
  compression:
    enabled: false
  display-nombre: myapp

spring:
  application.name: myapp
  data:
    rest:
      defaultPageSize: 10
      maxPageSize: 50
  datasource:
    driverClassName: org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver
    url: ${base.datasource.url}
    username: ${base.datasource.username}
    password: ${base.datasource.password}
    testWhileIdle: true
    validationQuery: SELECT 1
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
      naming-strategy: org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
    show-sql: ${base.jpa.show-sql}
  http:
    multipart:
      maxFileSize: ${base.maxUploadFileSize}
      maxRequestSize: ${base.maxUploadFileSize}

logging.level.org.hibernate: ${base.logging.level.org.hibernate}

debug: ${base.debug}
```

EDIT 2:

This the jar file included in dependencies:

[image]

EDIT 3:

The is the log shown before the actual exception:

```
28-Dec-2018 13:39:19.277 INFORMATION [http-nio-8080-exec-57] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.undeploy Repliegue (undeploy) de la aplicaciÃ³n web que tiene como trayectoria de contexto [/salesforce]
28-Dec-2018 13:39:19.332 INFORMATION [http-nio-8080-exec-60] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Desplieque del descriptor de configuraciÃ³n [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\conf\Catalina\localhost\myapp.xml]
28-Dec-2018 13:39:19.334 WARNING[http-nio-8080-exec-60] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor The path attribute with value [/myapp] in deployment descriptor [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\conf\Catalina\localhost\myapp.xml] has been ignored
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.4.5.RELEASE)

2018-12-28 13:39:31.408  INFO 17740 --- [io-8080-exec-60] c.p.e.m.s.CustomApplication         : Starting CustomApplication on MANAGER with PID 17740 (C:\thepath\app\WEB-INF\classes started by Jaime in C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\bin)
2018-12-28 13:39:31.414  INFO 17740 --- [io-8080-exec-60] c.p.e.m.s.SalesforceWSApplication        : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-12-28 13:39:31.533  INFO 17740 --- [io-8080-exec-60] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@3128ac95: startup date [Fri Dec 28 13:39:31 CLST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-12-28 13:39:40.725  INFO 17740 --- [io-8080-exec-60] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f486f241] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-12-28 13:39:40.965  INFO 17740 --- [io-8080-exec-60] .w.s.a.s.AnnotationActionEndpointMapping : Supporting [WS-Addressing August 2004, WS-Addressing 1.0]
2018-12-28 13:39:41.130  INFO 17740 --- [io-8080-exec-60] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4fef2d42] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-12-28 13:39:41.609  INFO 17740 --- [io-8080-exec-60] o.s.w.c.ContextLoader                    : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 10077 ms
2018-12-28 13:39:45.015  INFO 17740 --- [io-8080-exec-60] o.s.b.w.s.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2018-12-28 13:39:45.017  INFO 17740 --- [io-8080-exec-60] o.s.b.w.s.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'messageDispatcherServlet' to [/services/*]
2018-12-28 13:39:45.018  INFO 17740 --- [io-8080-exec-60] o.s.b.w.s.FilterRegistrationBean         : Mapping filter: 'errorPageFilter' to: [/*]
2018-12-28 13:39:45.018  INFO 17740 --- [io-8080-exec-60] o.s.b.w.s.FilterRegistrationBean         : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-12-28 13:39:45.018  INFO 17740 --- [io-8080-exec-60] o.s.b.w.s.FilterRegistrationBean         : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2018-12-28 13:39:45.018  INFO 17740 --- [io-8080-exec-60] o.s.b.w.s.FilterRegistrationBean         : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2018-12-28 13:39:45.018  INFO 17740 --- [io-8080-exec-60] o.s.b.w.s.FilterRegistrationBean         : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2018-12-28 13:39:45.512  WARN 17740 --- [io-8080-exec-60] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).
2018-12-28 13:39:45.527  INFO 17740 --- [io-8080-exec-60] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-12-28 13:39:45.535 ERROR 17740 --- [io-8080-exec-60] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************
```

Comment: Sounds like a required database jar is missing in wherever your libraries are.  What are you using to build your app with (ant, maven, etc...)?

Comment: It is maven.If I see applications.parameters.yml file I can see this: driverClassName: org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver under datasource group. Then, I  search for that class in Runtime dependencies node and mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar is present, which has that class.

Comment: How is Tomcat started in your app (Spring, custom main class, etc...)?

Comment: Is the database jar included in your deployment?

Comment: I have edited the question to show the main class and also the full application.parameters.yml file.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen i have edited the question to add a picture that shows the JAR file included.

Comment: Have you tried manually specifying your `${base.datasource...` properties?  Curious if that makes a difference...

Comment: @ZackMacomber yes.. that did not make any difference. i have updated the question again showing you the log before "APPLICATION FAILED TO START" error. It shows another exception "Exception encountered during context initialization"

Comment: @ZackMacomber Also, if i try to start the application using Tomcat manager, this error occurs: FAILED - Found exception [org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/salesforce]]]

Comment: @ZackMacomber Oher curious fact. I have read that to get rid of that error, I can add spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration to application.properties file. I don't have such a file, but I do application.parameters.yml I think it is equivalent. I have added that configuration but the same error happens. To test, I have generated a syntax error in that yml file but no error regarding this file was logged, so I think that yml file is not taken into account. That file is at src/main/resources folder.

Comment: Find the core exception causing all the others.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen what?

Comment: So the yml file isn't being loaded?  If it's not being loaded, all those parameters aren't being loaded either.

Comment: @ZackMacomber my theory is that the yml is not loaded.... the question now is: why? the file is called application.parameters.yml and is inside src/main/resources folder

Comment: @ZackMacomber maybe the file is not taken into account because the variable interpolation is not working?

Comment: @jstuardo You are talking about the outer most exceptions but they have a cause, that have another cause etc until you reach the actual exception triggering the whole avalanche.  THAT exception is important, the others are just relaying the fact up through layers and layers.

Answer (score 0):

Finally the problem was due to variable interpolation. I have defined the variables before the usage, in the same file, and it worked.

Regards
Jaime